# What does the symbol ? mean in a URL?

Tags: url, variables, query-string

What does the symbol ? mean in a URL?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

That portion of the URL (ie. after the `?`) is known as the query string.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string

It is used to pass parameters into web applications.

For example, in ASP.NET I might have an `.aspx` page like so:
http://example.com/myapp/default.aspx

Inside my codebehind for that page I can look for the presence of any query string parameters:

```
string paramValue = Request.QueryString["param"];
```

So if someone visits my page with the URL of http://example.com/myapp/default.aspx?param=abcd
Then the value of `paramValue` will be "abcd".

Comment: I love the example as one +1 for being you buddy!

Answer (score 9):

[RFC](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2616.html) for http protocol, section 3.2.2 `http URL`

"?" - is delimiter between "absolute path" and "query"