# How to (correctly) create mailto URL (URI) in Java?

Tags: java, uri, mailto

Given:

```java
String email1 = "simple@example.org";

// legal email address according to wikipedia [1]
String email2 = "\"()<>[]:,;@\\\"!#$%&'*+-/=?^_`{}| ~.a\"@example.org";
```

What is the best/correct way to create a mailto: URI (in the form of a String object)?

I tried:

```java
String uri = new URI("mailto", the_email_address, null).toString();
```

This is the closest I got, but it does not encode the question-mark (?) in the local part of the email address, but according to [RFC 6068](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6068) it should. It also fails on examples in the RFC, like *"not@me"@example.org* or *unlikely?address@example.com*.

[1] [Valid_email_addresses examples](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email_address#Valid_email_addresses)

PS: There is some useful information in [Should plus be encoded in mailto: hyperlinks?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/15920/should-plus-be-encoded-in-mailto-hyperlinks)

---

*I settled for this as a solution:*

```
import org.apache.http.client.utils.URIBuilder;
// from Apache HttpClient
// maven group: org.apache.httpcomponents artifact: httpclient

String emailURL = new URIBuilder().setScheme("mailto").setPath(the_email_address).toString();
```

Comment: I notice that your example is creating a URI from email1 however it does not have a question mark, did you mean to use email2?

Comment: The question mark is in other example. That comment was general: the used method doesn't work if the mail address has a question mark in it.

Comment: @DavidBalažic are you not able to use Apache commons URI builder? or is ur requirement different?

Answer (score 12):

You have to manually percent encode/escape the `?` and `&`.

```
String email2 = "\"()<>[]:,;@\\\"!#$%&'*+-/=?^_`{}| ~.a\"@example.org";
String uri2 = (new URI("mailto", email2, null)).toString().replace("?", "%3F").replace("&", "%26");
```

So it seems that the `?` and `&` symbols are not being correctly escaped in the URI. Anything after the `?` is ignored in the URI because that symbol is reserved for "query strings" in URLs. Reference [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5307548/what-does-the-symbol-mean-in-a-url).

According to [this](http://search.cpan.org/dist/URI/lib/URI/Escape.pm) and the reference documents, we need to escape `&` as well. For some reason, Java is not doing that for us. In fact, RFC 6068 even states:

> A number of characters that can appear in  MUST be
>          percent-encoded.  These are the characters that cannot appear in
>          a URI according to [STD66] as well as "%" (because it is used for
>          percent-encoding) and all the characters in gen-delims except "@"
>          and ":" (i.e., "/", "?", "#", "[", and "]").  Of the characters
>          in sub-delims, at least the following also have to be percent-
>          encoded: "&", ";", and "=".

The way to fix it (somewhat of a hack, but it works) is to manually escape these characters using a `%` followed by 2 digit ASCII hex value for symbol. Reference [this](http://www.unix-manuals.com/refs/misc/ascii-table.html).

I tested by pasting the resulting string into Chrome and it correctly opened up my default email with an email to

```
"()<>[]:,; @\"!#$%&'*+-/=?^_`{}| ~.a"@example.org
```

**More Research**

So it seems that Java's URI class uses [RFC 2396](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2396.txt), which states:

> If the data for a URI component would conflict with the
>      reserved purpose, then the conflicting data must be escaped before
>      forming the URI.
>
> ```
>  reserved = ";" | "/" | "?" | ":" | "@" | "&" | "=" | "+" |
>             "$" | ","
> ```
>
> The "reserved" syntax class above refers to those characters that are
>      allowed within a URI, but which **may** not be allowed within a
>      particular component of the generic URI syntax;

Answer (score 4):

**You will have to use [Apache Commons URI](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/client/utils/URIBuilder.html) builder**

> The value is expected to be unescaped and may contain non ASCII
>   characters.

**You can not directly use java uri class** [Java URI doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URI.html#URI(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) says 
All punctuation characters are Reserved together with those in the string **"?/[]@"** are **reserved**.

> Java's URI class uses [RFC 2396](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2396.txt), which states:If the data for a URI component would conflict with the
>      reserved purpose, then the conflicting data must be escaped before
>      forming the URI.
>
> ```
>  reserved = ";" | "/" | "?" | ":" | "@" | "&" | "=" | "+" |
>             "$" | ","
> ```
>
> You can use `java.net.URLEncoder` to encode the user_name and  then
>   use encoded username to create the URI `String uri = new URI("mailto",
>   the_email_address, null).toString();`
>   or
>   You can manually percent encode/escape the ? and &.
>
> ```
> String email2 = "\"()<>[]:,;@\\\"!#$%&'*+-/=?^_`{}| ~.a\"@example.org";
> String uri2 = (new URI("mailto", email2, null)).toString().replace("?", "%3F").replace("&", "%26");
> ```
>
> In JavaScript you can use the `encodeURI()` function. PHP has the
>   `rawurlencode()` function, and ASP has the `Server.URLEncode()` function.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to use the URI.create(String uri) static method to create your mailto uri, instead of using the "new" constructor. For example, this returns a valid URI (I'm using jdk 7):

```
URI.create("mailto:john?doe@foo.bar.com");
```

I hope it helps.

Cheers.

Comment: JavaDoc says: "This method is provided for use in situations where it is known that the given string is a legal URI" So I can use this method, when I already have a solution. ;)